# Ways to prevent employees from talking not related things during meeting

Tags: relationships, meetings

There are many instances that I've attended a meeting. During the first 30 minutes the meeting is very okay, every employees are focused on the meeting, giving ideas and you can really see the brainstorming.

The problem comes when the duration of the meeting stays longer than 30 minutes, the employees will start asking unnecessary questions that are not related to the topic, some of them are boasting about their background, some are just chitchatting. Those things makes the meeting longer, this makes me unproductive.

My question is what should I do? Should I excuse myself?(*How?*), do I have the authority to do that? Assuming that I'am just a regular employee among the company.

Comment: But what's your goal? To get them fired? More... permanently eliminated? Remove their influence? Get them to stop talking? How to stop being a blind "yes man" yourself? How to better utilize this person's experience? There are a lot of things you might be hoping to do by "deal with" but nothing in your question right now indicates _which_ option you want to do. Presumably you are hoping to get him to stop talking about his background unnecessarily, which is what I have edited your question to reflect, but if this is not the case feel free to [edit] it again.

Comment: Yeah, yeah @enderland you are right about my point. I just want him to stop talking if it is not necessary. :) Thanks for editing.

Comment: Please see my revised question, I managed to edit it in such a way that there can be a definite answer.

Comment: Its the person chairing the meeting's job to run the meeting - maybe buy them a copy of Citrines ABC of chairmanship and leave it on their desk

Comment: I reopened and marked this as a duplicate. Thanks for the edits and clarifying your question to turn it into something more lasting for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks @jmort253, well done. I'm learning now how to ask a good question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a long story short, you don't have to keep taking it on the chin. Excuse yourself and get back to doing the work that your company is paying you to do, and the company is certainly not paying to be his private babysitting service for up to 90 minutes of every working of the week!

I understand that there may be a possibility that this manager may report you to your own manager, but your own manager will have a hell of a time justifying nailing you for getting back to doing the work he assigned to you on behalf of the company. If he does nail you - and this is unlikely, report him immediately to HR because you being pressured to be this manager's nanny for up to 90 minutes of every working day - that does not pass the laugh test.

Comment: +1 for answering the question exatly, and identifying the possible consequences. ;)